# Quick one on Big Query SQL-Ecommerce Data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to replicate the Google Analyitcs data in Big Query but couldnt do that.

Basically I am using Custom Dimension 40 (user subscription status)

[image]

but I am getting wrong numbers in BQ.

Can someone help me on this?

I am using this query but couldn't find it out the exact one.

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT value FROM hits.customDimensions where index=40) AS UserStatus,
    COUNT(hits.transaction.transactionId) AS Unique_Purchases
FROM
    `xxxxxxxxxxxxx.ga_sessions_2020*` AS GA,  --new rollup
    UNNEST(GA.hits) AS hits 
WHERE
    (SELECT  value FROM hits.customDimensions where index=40) IN ("xx001","xxx002")
GROUP BY 1
```

I am getting this from big query which is wrong.

I have check out the dates also but dont know why its wrong.

[image]

Comment: this is basically from ecommerce data but I dont know why its wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather unclear.  But because you want something to be unique and numbers are mysteriously not what you want, I would suggest using `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT hits.transaction.transactionId) AS Unique_Purchases
```

Comment: I have tried this as well but cannot see those numbers exactly as GA.In GA the numbers are doubled but in Big Query its less than half and the correct stats is GA so I want to replicate those.Edited the question if you see this

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you imported Google Analytics data into Bigquery and you are trying to group the [custom dimension](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en) with index 40 and values ("xx001","xxx002") in order to know how many [hit transactions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#transaction-hit) were performed in function of these dimension values.

Replicating your scenario and trying to execute the query you posted, I got the following error.

[image: scalar-error]

However, I created a query that could help with your use-case. At first, it selects the transactionId and dimension values with the transactionId different from null and with index value equal to 40, then the grouping is done by the dimension value, filtered with values equals to "xx001"&"xxx002".

```
WITH tx AS (
   SELECT
      HIT.transaction.transactionId,
      CD.value
   FROM
      `xxxxxxxxxxxxx.ga_sessions_2020*` AS GA,
      UNNEST(GA.hits) AS HIT,
      UNNEST(HIT.customDimensions) AS CD
   WHERE
      HIT.transaction.transactionId IS NOT NULL
   AND
      CD.index = 40
)

SELECT tx.value AS UserStatus, count(tx.transactionId) AS Unique_Purchases
FROM tx
WHERE tx.value IN ("xx001","xx002")
GROUP BY tx.value
```

For further details about the format and schema of the data that is imported into BigQuery, I found [this document](http://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-apache-hive-on-cloud-dataproc).

Comment: it i just giving me 1 and 2 values but not the actual number of subscriptions.
false result :/

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood the results you wanted to achieve. In your question I believe that you want to get a number of transactions per subscription status instead of a number of subscriptions. Could you help to clarify what you mean with your previous answer or elaborate more on your question?